# Mybatis - how to fire query dynamically

Tags: spring, mybatis, ibatis

I am looking for mybatis tag, wherein i can fire whole query  dynamically. I want construct complete query as parameter in code and fire it from mybatis. Is there any way, wherein i can do that?

Comment: Rather than constructing your query in code ,You better do the same using dynamic SQLs in mybatis passing in required condition parameters. Mybatis has a great support for evaluating conditions in the SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following example can give you a different kind of idea the kind of dynamic query supported by Mybatis:

```
   <select id="runQuery" resultType="map" parameterType="map" databaseId="mysql">
        SELECT
        <if test="disableDistinct == false">
        DISTINCT
        </if>
        ${columnList}
        FROM ${fromClause}
        <if test="whereClause != null">
        WHERE ${whereClause}
        </if>
        <if test="orderClause != null">
        ORDER BY ${orderClause}
        </if>
        <if test="totalRows != null">
        LIMIT ${totalRows}
        </if>
    </select>
```